# how to deal with error in unity (Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices)

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

how to fix this error, my unity version is 2023.2.3f1

Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found.
at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExtractZip (System.String zipFile, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] extractFilenames, System.String outputDirectory, System.Boolean update) [0x00130] in <6107d0e161ea44f5b1a06a3cb63d4bc0>:0  at Google.GradleWrapper.Extract (Google.Logger logger) [0x00045] in <6107d0e161ea44f5b1a06a3cb63d4bc0>:0  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.GradleResolution (System.String destinationDirectory, System.String androidSdkPath, System.Boolean logErrorOnMissingArtifacts, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action`1[T] resolutionComplete) [0x00085] in <6107d0e161ea44f5b1a06a3cb63d4bc0>:0
at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.DoResolutionUnsafe (System.String destinationDirectory, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action resolutionComplete) [0x000ba] in <6107d0e161ea44f5b1a06a3cb63d4bc0>:0
at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver+c__AnonStorey13.<>m__1D () [0x00000] in <6107d0e161ea44f5b1a06a3cb63d4bc0>:0
at Google.RunOnMainThread.ExecuteNext () [0x0003d] in :0
0x00007fff31baacbd (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007fff31bb2559 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007fff33320c19 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007fff30cae5cc (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x000002a5412b3d6d (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log_Injected (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,UnityEngine.Bindings.ManagedSpanWrapper&,intptr)
0x000002a5412b3c23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x000002a5412b383b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x000002a5412b3580 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x000002a5412b4275 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x000002a3a487e6fb (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext ()
0x000002a3a487e493 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:m__A ()
0x000002a3a487e3e6 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
0x000002a3a487e35b (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
0x000002a3a487d763 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:Run (System.Action,bool)
0x000002a5412a9293 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:DoResolution (string,bool,System.Action)
0x000002a541274d63 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe (System.Action`1<bool>,bool,bool,bool) 0x000002a54127413b (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver/<ScheduleResolve>c__AnonStorey1E:<>m__3F () 0x000002a541273fc3 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob () 0x000002a541273c93 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ScheduleResolve (bool,bool,System.Action`1,bool)
0x000002a541273733 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve (System.Action)
0x000002a5412735b3 (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:m__47 ()
0x000002a3a487f2cd (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs ()
0x000002a3a487e4ab (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:m__A ()
0x000002a3a487e3e6 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
0x000002a3a487e35b (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
0x000002a3bc690b90 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
0x000002a3a4b264a5 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007fff373d694e (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007fff37318464 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3068)
0x00007fff37318550 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3115)
0x00007fff31ad4da4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007fff31aafdf3 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007fff31aab085 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007fff31c33bab (Unity) Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallUpdateFunctions
0x00007fff32691e0d (Unity) SceneTracker::Update
0x00007fff327a945a (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007fff32be3f0a (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007fff32be9ddd (Unity) UnityMain
0x00007ff6f8e42cda (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007fff7c347344 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007fff7e3226b1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

Answer (score 0):

1. Solved this by (Workaround):
   Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Configuration -> Allow downloads over HTTP
   set "Always allowed"...
2. Github Link : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/679
3. Github Link : https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-unity/issues/266
4. How to Handle Errors in Unity : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BnPCav-vfc